# link onclick does not submit form

Tags: javascript, php

i have a db records echoed out and formatted in a table with a delete link(icon) on each table row, indexed with a while loop as the data gets fetched from db. 
On clicking the delete icon, i expect the particular indexed row to get deleted from db and also from the table .
Here are my codes:

```
<script>
function submitForm(){
document.getElementById("myform").submit()
}</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>

 <?php 

$rowIndex = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result){
 $user = $row[0];
 $address=$row[1];
 $phone = $row[2];
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$user.'</td>
<td>'.$address.'</td>
<td>'.$phone.'</td>
<td><a href="" onclick="javascript: submitForm()">Delete(icon)</a>
</tr>'
$rowIndex+=1;

}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<form method ="post" id ="myform" action ="test.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="del">
</form>
```

on clicking the 'Delete' Link , i expect the javascript to submit the form and move to 'test.php'(though i intend to remain on same form, but that way i will know my form ACTUALLY got submitted). Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? Have you tried `onclick="submitForm()"`? Have you tried using a `<button>` instead of `<a>`?

Comment: Try `onclick="submitForm(); return false"`

Comment: Tnx Phil! please can u explain why the return false. That alone made the code work! please alittle explanation and i will vote as answer to this qxn

Comment: `return false` stops the link from navigating to its `href` attribute value

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test javascript form test </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" id="name"><br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password"><br>
<button onclick="data()" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
function data(){
   var name = $("#name").val();
   var pass = $("#password").val();
   alert(name);
   alert(pass);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```